# What would be the best, cheapest, smallest way to power a Bluetooth bone conduction headset project?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, headphones, digital-audio

Please, be forewarned, I'm an idiot when it comes to electronic builds. The last thing I soldered was a pick-up in a guitar kit I built, and the thing still isn't grounded right.

I'm trying to build a Bluetooth bone conduction headset, on the cheap, that will fit into a baseball hat discreetly, so the smaller the better.

The "headphones" will be two 20mm piezo transducers connected to a Bluetooth module.  [This is what I was thinking.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08G8JTDVC)

[image]

I've seen a similar project (but with a regular, non-Bluetooth headphone connection) work at 5W, so that's my goal.

My initial idea was to power all of it using two CR2032 coin batteries and putting a linear regulator between them and the BT module, but am being told that's going to be underpowered.

Is there a power solution strong and small enough and if so, what would that be?

Also, would it need a voltage regulator, and if so, what kind?

If you could offer any help on components and such, that would be amazing too.

Comment: Hmm some factors you may not be aware of are that 5W is *a lot* of power in something that has to fit in a baseball cap.  Safely attaching batteries will be a major concern if it can be done at all(smallest form factor is Li-Ion which would be dangerous to have large quantities of near your head.).  If you want to go ahead with this project I'd suggest you try the non-bluetooth version first because it probably had more than enough huge challenges.  Once you're good enough at that to build one that runs on a lot less than 5W, then figure out the bluetooth part and how to conceal it.

Comment: When I was flying models, I used to buy a bucketload of stuff from HobbyKing. The local hobby shop wanted $17 for a new heli battery, the online mob, $1.10 I bought a dozen of them for less than 1 of the locals. They were 130 mAh lipo cells. They've since been discontinued, but many others are available. $4.41 AUD will get a 300mAh cell. It's 43x17x6mm and weighs 9g. It's probably got a protection board inside.. I've also bought 5v regulators from them in the past - all RC radios wanted 5v, so there's lots of solutions to create 5v from the main battery pack.

Comment: I'm basing it on this project: https://techiesms.com/misc-projects/3-projects-using-bone-conduction/ and figured the amplifier swap and power source would be the only difference. Bluetooth units akin to the project I'm trying already exist: https://maxvirtual.com/Cynaps-Classic-Bluetooth-Self-Install-Kit-p192059203

Comment: I probably paid about 3 or 4 bucks for the 2 step-down converters I bought. They'll go from 12v to 5v at 3 amps - yep, 15 watts. And they stay cool. The RC market can be a source for all kinds of goodies these days, whether you're interested in RC or not!

Comment: I was looking at Lipo cells and thought I might daisy chain them and then step them down to get the 5W sound. Unless that's unrealistic?

Comment: I’d be worried about the BT radiation giving me cancer of the bone.

Comment: Why 5W, that sounds like a lot of power. Normal headphones are on the order of a few mW

Comment: @r_ahlskog:  [Bone conduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bone_conduction) is basically rattling your head so hard that bones in your inner ear move.  There's no audible sound transmitted through the air.  It takes a good bit of power to rattle a head that hard through the skin.

Comment: @EllisMorgan:  The example you linked to uses a 3 watt amplifier.  It is doubtful that it actually produces 3 watts of output power.  It is operating from 5V.  The battery is a 9V "transistor" battery that isn't made to deliver high current. 3 watts at 5 volts means 0.6 amperes of current from that puny little battery - that ain't happening.  The total power is probably much lower than you expect.

Comment: @JRE yes I know what they are, got to test a commercial pair a while back. Judging from the size of them and battery life I would not think they output serious amounts of power. 8 hours of use from something that all in all weighs 28 grams.

Answer (score 1):

I won't promise this is the "best, cheapest, smallest" way to power your bone conduction hat, but I recommend you consider **zinc-air** cells, better known as a "hearing aid battery". Why:

- Cell voltage is 1.4 V, just connect 4 in series to get 5.6 V.
- High current capability
- Disposable, instead of rechargeable -- easier for beginners
- Environmentally sound -- no dangerous elements, toss in trash
- Lightweight -- one of the two chemicals is just air!
- Safe next to your head -- used in thousands of hearing aids
- PCB holders easily available
- Inexpensive when bought in reasonable quantity

Zinc-air cells are different from other technologies in that they have a fixed lifespan of about 2 weeks. When purchased they have a seal that keeps air out. Once you pull that off, the chemical reaction begins whether you draw current or not. Look for ones designated for cochlear implants for the highest current capacity.